# Linear transformation proof

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Guys I'm stuck with a problem of linear algebra. I have a linear transformation $L:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ and I need to prove that $\mathbb{R}^3 = \text{ker}(L) \oplus \text{im}(L) $. I don't really seem able of tackling this problem by using the definitions... Any hint or explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have forget to write that $\mathbb{R}^3 = \text{ker}(L) \oplus \text{im}(L) $ means that for all $\text{v} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ there exists $\text{x}\in\text{ker}(L)$ and $\text{y}\in\text{im}(L)$ such that $\text{v}=\text{x}+\text{y}$ and $\text{ker}(T) \cap \text{im}(T) = \{0\}$

Comment: This could only be true relative to a particular $L$. So, define $L$ and we've got a decent chance of helping you.

Comment: I have edited the post. $L$ is not defined, only the explanation above is given

Comment: Well, the assertion is not true in general, so you *must* have some more information about $L$.

Comment: As the current answer shows, the statement is *not* true in general. You need to add some more information other than the definition of the direct sum (which is well known). What sort of linear transformation is $L$? There must be some information.

Comment: I have no information about $L$, this is a question I've posed to myself while self studying linear algebra... Anyway, the answer given is satisfactory and helped me understand a lot of things!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equality  isn't always true without further assumption: take for example the matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
We have $A^2=0$ so $\operatorname{Im}A\subset \ker A$ and $\ker A\ne \Bbb R^3$.

Comment: I don't really get your point. By the computations that I've made, $\text{ker}A=(1,1,0)$ and $\text{im}A=(0,0,z)$ why the above relationship is true?

Comment: No the image of $A$ is the span of $(1,0,0)$.